# Unable to read package from path 'CassandraCSharpDriver.3.0.0.nupkg' Error - installing the CassandraCSharpDriver package

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am trying to install the CassandraCSharpDriver package in Visual Studio 2012 with .NET Framework 4.5.
I installed the dependency package lz4net, which worked without any issues.
When trying to install the CassandraCSharpDriver, I get the error:

```
Unable to read package from path 'CassandraCSharpDriver.3.0.0.nupkg'
```

I cleared the package cache, i updated the nuget.org package and I only have lz4net package installed.

Comment: I've just tested using VS 2013, .NET 4.5.0 and .NET 4.5.1., I was able to install the package and build. Are you using the VS Package dialog or command line? Can you post the packages.config you are using?